# pandas groupby streak of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dir':[0,0,0,1,1,0,1], 'price': [100, 102, 110, 120, 125, 200, 210]})

   dir  price
0    0    100
1    0    102
2    0    110
3    1    120
4    1    125
5    0    200
6    1    210
```

and I want to groupby 0s and the 1s after it. My desired outcome looks like this:

```
   dir  price
0    0    100
1    0    102
2    0    110
3    1    120
4    1    125

   dir  price
5    0    200
6    1    210
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `diff` with `cumsum` if it is `1` and `0` you will start count as a new group , so that the `diff` should be equal(`eq`) to `-1`

```
for x , y in df.groupby(df.dir.diff().eq(-1).cumsum()): 
    print(y)



   dir  price
0    0    100
1    0    102
2    0    110
3    1    120
4    1    125
   dir  price
5    0    200
6    1    210
d={x: y  for x , y in df.groupby(df.dir.diff().eq(-1).cumsum())}
```