# groupby streak of numbers in one column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'b': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
    }
)
```

And this is the way that I want to group it:

```
2   1  1
3   0  1
4   0  1
5   0  1
6   0  0
7   0  0

9   1  0
10  0  1

13  1  1
14  0  1
15  0  1
16  0  0
17  0  1
```

I want to group this dataframe based on values of column b. The first thing to do is to find the 1s in column a. And then I want to continue as long as there is 0 in column b and after that get the row after that 0 as well.
If the value in a is 1 and the value in b is 0 I want to continue only for one row.
Basically I want to stop as soon as there is a 0 in column b and then go on one row after that 0.

I have tried these two posts: [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046286/groupby-two-columns-in-pandas), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986311/pandas-groupby-streak-of-numbers) but still have problem to solve this.

I have tried to group them by: `df.b.diff().cumsum()` but it doesn't give me what I want

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BeRT2me the two posts that I have linked. and also tried to groupby b.diff() but could'nt find a way

Comment: For start I would stop using the word "groupby" which is a method in `pandas` that has nothing to do with what you are trying to do, and is misleading the readers.

Comment: Those posts are from literally 3+ years ago... you haven't tried anything different since then?

Comment: @BeRT2me I did try but I have problem with grouping that involves the start of streak or end of streak. I know SO rules that I should try but I did try. These kind of groupbys are just not so easy for me because I haven't use them often

Comment: Do you want to end up with groups (what my answer does), or a single dataframe (what my answer could do with a tiny update)?

Comment: @mozway Actually I need a single df. Thanks man. You're just so good at it. I know this was not easy :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cumsum` to create a helper Series for filtering/grouping, then subfilter each group with a boolean mask:

```
group = df['a'].cumsum()

for k, g in df[group>0].groupby(group):
    # drop rows 2 places after the first 0
    m = g['b'].ne(0).cummin().shift(2, fill_value=True)
    print(g[m])
```

Output:

```
   a  b
2  1  1
3  0  1
4  0  1
5  0  1
6  0  0
7  0  0

    a  b
9   1  0
10  0  1

    a  b
13  1  1
14  0  1
15  0  1
16  0  0
17  0  1
```

##### As single dataframe:

Either run the above and `concat`, or:

```
group = df['a'].cumsum()
m = df['b'].ne(0).groupby(group).apply(lambda x: x.cummin().shift(2, fill_value=True))

out = df[group.gt(0)&m]
```

Output:

```
    a  b
2   1  1
3   0  1
4   0  1
5   0  1
6   0  0
7   0  0
9   1  0
10  0  1
13  1  1
14  0  1
15  0  1
16  0  0
17  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd: pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.loc[:dd.query("b==0").head(1)
                       .index.values[0]+1,:'b'].pipe(print)
df.assign(col1=(df.a==1).cumsum())\
    .query('col1>0')\
    .groupby('col1').apply(function1)
    
    
    
    a  b
2  1  1
3  0  1
4  0  1
5  0  1
6  0  0
7  0  0
    a  b
9   1  0
10  0  1
    a  b
13  1  1
14  0  1
15  0  1
16  0  0
17  0  1
```